# Update values in array using lib in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to update values in my array using [this lib](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

My code so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text } from "react-native";
import update from "immutability-helper";

export default function App() {
  const [currentElement, setCurrentElement] = React.useState(0);
  const [initialArray, setInitialArray] = React.useState([0, 0, 0]);

  const array = [0, 0, 0];
  function nextEle() {
    setCurrentElement(currentElement + 1);
  }
  function prevEle() {
    setCurrentElement(currentElement - 1);
  }
  function setNum(num) {
    setInitialArray(update(array, { [currentElement]: { $apply: [num]} }));
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="set array[0] = 1" onClick={() => setNum(21)} />
      <Button title="set array[1] = 2" onClick={() => setNum(212)} />
      <Button title="set array[2] = 3" onClick={() => setNum(231)} />
      <Button title="Next element" onPress={nextEle} />
      <Button title="Prev element" onPress={prevEle} />
      <Text>{initialArray[currentElement]}</Text>
      <Text>current element is {currentElement}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    top: 10,
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: "80%",
    position: "absolute",
  },
});
```

Values doesn't update at all! I read documentation carefully but i couldn't understand how to fix that. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setNum(num) {
  setInitialArray(update(array, { [currentElement]: { $set: num } }));
}
```